# android studio 2.0 preview emulator not show new buttons

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

I downloaded Android Studio 2.0 preview, I installed, and I think it's work, for example "instant run" it is work fine,

but the emulator not show the new buttons,

I read that I can use my Stable Android Studio and Android Studio 2.0 but I think the emulator still work with Stable Android Studio and not with the new emulator,

well, I updated the android sdk (api 23), I created a new AVD, but I can't watch the new buttons, and I can't resize the screen (option on Android Studio 2.0 emulator)

do you know what I have to do?

PD: 
[the new buttons that don't show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReA2m.png)

[my emulator and android studio 2.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA1Lm.png)

Answer (score 1):

To get the new emulator features, you need to install the **Android SDK Tools** for **Preview channel** shown below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the answer is that android emulator was released few hours ago!

[the notice on http://android-developers.blogspot.com](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/12/android-studio-20-preview-android.html)

[explication for install new emulator](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/emulator)